# Teams for education?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, education

Is there a pricing tier of Teams geared towards education/academia/students in the works? This would be great for our research lab if it was more economical.

Comment: How many users would you approximate describing a general need / use case there? What about long periods where seats aren't used (e.g. semester breaks), would that be seen as wasteful to those dealing with the accounting?

Comment: @TimPost Out of the two labs I'm regularly involved with, they both have ~20 active users on Slack, and I would expect each to also be active on a Teams platform. The turnover tends to be on the scale of years for most users with no real breaks of use (summer is still active). One of the labs often hosts graduate students from other departments and universities though, who spend a lot of time getting trained on equipment--this is where I think a Q&A platform would really be a timesaver. There are maybe a handful of these transient members at any given time in addition to the regular users.

Comment: To corroborate, @TimPost, while I don't think Teams is an option for our lab, we have many (grad) students who stay with us for years and we actually get an increase in undergrad students during the summer, not a decline. Some students stay in town (or are locals) and do more full-time work with us.

Comment: Getting students hooked on the addictive simplicity of Stack Overflow's interface for sharing knowledge, and spreading that addiction wherever they end up going after University, does sound like enough of a marketing win to justify offering discounted licenses...

Comment: @TimPost To give another anecdote, we wouldn't consider paying for the regular Slack plan at $2000/year for 25 users. But the same plan for educational users is $300/year (now a no-brainer). A 25 person Stack Overflow team would be $1000/yr--getting that down to at or below cost of an annual Slack education plan would probably make it a no-brainer as well.

Comment: I'm letting the teams team know about this post (so it gets noticed), this is definitely not a bad suggestion.

Comment: @TimPost It is heartening to know that the teams team is teeming with people willing to team up to tackle this opportunity!

Comment: Probably not a huge deal, but one thing to consider is the potential grey area between a university IT/software engineering shop and an academic lab environment.

Answer (score 11):

Non-profit organizations can apply for a special plan that's free up to 250 users. Proof of nonprofit status must be submitted by a private nonprofit organization with the application. Any of the following is acceptable evidence of nonprofit status:

- A reference to the applicant organization’s listing in the Internal
  Revenue Service’s (IRS) most recent list of tax-exempt organizations
  described in section 501(c)(3) of the IRS Code
- A copy of a currently valid IRS tax exemption certificate;
- A statement from a State taxing body, State Attorney General, or
  other appropriate State Official certifying that the applicant
  organization has nonprofit status and that none of the net earnings
  accrue to any private shareholders or individuals;
- A certified copy of the organization’s certificate of incorporation
  or similar document that clearly establishes nonprofit status;
- Any of the above proof for a State or national parent organization
  and a statement signed by the parent organization that the applicant
  organization is a local nonprofit affiliate.

If you'd like to apply for the non-profit plan, [please contact our Support team](https://stackoverflow.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/26) with the required documentation.

Comment: what would be a very broad timeline for an announcement (regardless of the direction of the announcement). I am asking because I would like to know whether I should wait a few months, or should I look and settle for something else for the course I am organizing in January 2020.

Comment: It's a shame this has't been picked up... we're having just the same conversation at work right now.

Comment: Are there any news? I would like to use Teams for a school with approx. 110 parents and teachers. Paying 600+$ bucks is out of question for us unfortunately