# Stack Overflow for Teams for Students?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

So, I saw this post about Stack Overflow for Teams becoming free for [teams of up to 50 people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362203/stack-overflow-for-teams-is-now-free-for-up-to-50-users-forever?cb=1), and a thought struck me after I took at look at the [Stack Overflow for Teams page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams): there doesn't seem to be any sort of student discount for SO for Teams. While smaller classes with 50 or fewer students can use the existing free option, classes with more students than that (like many university Computer Science classes) can't.

As a result, I think it might be a good idea for Stack Exchange corporate to consider implementing a free or discounted version of SO for Teams for students/educational institutions, since students trained in how to use SO for Teams at university are probably a lot more likely to carry on using it in their professional life afterwards.

Comment: There used to be a page on their help site indicating a 90% discount for nonprofit/education Teams, but that page seems to have disappeared.

Comment: I would guess that an institution might potentially have its own agreement/be able to negotiate its own agreement with enough seats, or even run an internal/enterprise instance. This might need staff to answer though

Comment: I'm curious - Teams is intended to be a long-term knowledge sharing tool. A single course at a university or college would last 3-6 months. We have a public site dedicated to the CS50 course at Harvard and the general value seems to be that it has years of questions from the course. If a student set up a Team, there's unlikely to be that continuity - the Team would exist for 6 months and then falter, leaving the content relatively useless. So... to get to my point... I see value in universities setting up Teams but what is your thoughts about how a student doing this would help their class?

Comment: @gparyani the discount for educational institutions still exists and is an option but requires the school to implement the Team, not the students.

Comment: @Catija "the Team would exist for 6 months and then falter, leaving the content relatively useless." The point would be to have the site active for those three to six months, at which point the university closes it and starts a new one for the next class. It's what my university does with Slack channels, for instance. The benefit to SE is to get the students used to working in that ecosystem, and hoping that they'll take it with them into their professional life.

Comment: Right... except that requires the university to do the work. Your question sounds more like you as a student want to set this up. You do mention the university as an option but that didn't seem like the primary actor in the situation you're discussing. "For students" to me implies that the students are the one setting up the Team.

Comment: @Catija When I went to university, most courses I took had a Piazza site for Q&A regarding the course, which would be used quite frequently by students. Problem is, Piazza isn't a very great Q&A engine compared to the SE engine; for example, it only allows students to post one community-wiki answer (meaning that if a student has already answered a question, another student can't post another one, they can only edit the existing one), and comments are per the entire post, not per individual question or answer.

Comment: Also, if the option is still provided, why was any mention of it removed from the help site?

Comment: @gparyani It [had been put on hold](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367566/teams-for-education) previously and the pages were removed because we weren't offering the discounts at the time. We'll look into the current status and what we want to advertise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We do offer non-profit organizations (who meet requirements) access to our Free plan for more than 50 users. Educational institutions who have a need should reach out to discuss pricing options for our paid plans directly. We can be reached at our [support portal](https://stackoverflow.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/26).